# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{2^k-1} 1/n^p < \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} (1/2^ { p-1})^n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

I was asked to show that the p-series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^p$ is convergent without using the integral and limit test. Also, I need to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{2^k-1} \frac{1}{n^p} < \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac{1}{2^ { p-1}}\right)^n$$ is one of the intermediate step. How can I derive this intermediate step ( using sub-sequence I think) and the following.

*I have google and also search here for helps, and I do see some similar question and good answers, but I still don't know how to derive that intermediate step and the rest.

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intermediate step inequality can be used to show that the $p$-series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^p$ is **convergent** for $p>1$ by recalling that the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ is convergent when $|x|<1$.

Hint for the intermediate step: for $k>1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2^k-1} \frac{1}{n^p}=\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} 
\sum_{n=2^{m}}^{2^{m+1}-1} \frac{1}{n^p}<
\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} 
\sum_{n=2^{m}}^{2^{m+1}-1} \frac{1}{(2^m)^p}.$$

Comment: hi, why is there a double summation? And how why is the right hand side larger than the left hand side ? Thank you!

Comment: In order to show the inequality it is useful to split the sum. The terms in the sum on the right are larger than the terms on the left.

Comment: Any further doubts? Are you able  to evaluate $$\sum_{n=2^{m}}^{2^{m+1}-1} \frac{1}{(2^m)^p}\;?$$

Comment: I can't !!! I have been thinking about this question for like the whole night !

Comment: The term in the sum does not depend on $n$!!!

Comment: but the right hand side is to the power of n ?!

Comment: Are you following my hint? I mean HERE: $$\sum_{n=2^{m}}^{2^{m+1}-1} \frac{1}{(2^m)^p}$$
the term in the sum does not depend on $n$ so...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84689/discussion-between-math-avengers-and-robert-z).